# Fastest rate of entangling atomic qubits

Tags: quantum-information, atomic-physics, quantum-computer

Many quantum computing systems, most notably trapped ions, propose to use optical heralded entanglement schemes to entangle small 'modules' of qubits that are further apart. Typically one puts two atoms into two different cavities and then repeatedly tries to catch photons from both at the same time (really just one photon, but in such a way that you can't tell from which atom the photon came). Last I checked, these schemes were prohibitively slow, like less than 1 kHz.

What is the current record for remote 2-atom Bell pairs generated per second? Note 'remote' can mean separated by ~meter distances, since that's still useful for modular quantum computation.

Or if you don't know the world-record holder at the moment, what is the order of magnitude of currently achievable rates?